# How to prove that the cosine of the angle of two vectors is preserved after rotating the vectors with the same angle?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we with linear algebra prove that if two vectors in 2 dimensions form an angle $\phi$ then by multiplying those two vectors with the same rotation matrix the cosine of the formed angle will be preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe use the fact that matrix corresponding to the rotation is orthogonal:
$$R^T = R^{-1}$$
and that the norm of a vector after rotation is the same as the original one:
$$||R \mathbf{v}|| = ||\mathbf{v}||$$

So, by direct computation, for two vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, you have:

$$ \cos(\alpha_{R\mathbf{v},R\mathbf{w}}) = \frac{<R\mathbf{v},R\mathbf{w}>}{||R\mathbf{v}|| \ ||R\mathbf{w}||} = \frac{\mathbf{v}^T R^T R \mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{v}|| \ ||\mathbf{w}||} =  \frac{\mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{w}}{||\mathbf{v}|| \ ||\mathbf{w}||} = \cos(\alpha_{\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}}) $$

Answer (score 1):

We have 
${\bf a}\cdot{\bf b} = {\bf a}^T{\bf b} = ab\cos\phi$. 
Let $R$ be the rotation matrix. 
Then
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf a}^T {\bf b} &\rightarrow& (R{\bf a})^T {R\bf b} \\
&=& {\bf a}^T R^T R {\bf b} \\
&=& {\bf a}^T {\bf b}, 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
since $R$ is orthogonal.